# Printing changes of two object in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

how can i print  changes of two same objects in asp.net? for example i have  two object of type car having some changes in properties. I want to show user that what actually changes in term of propertes are there in object in web view. is there any built in thing or open source? my objects can be nested too like Car object can have List of Drivers in it with some other properties.

Comment: *"my objects can be nested"* -- this is why there is no pre-made solution for this. It's impossible to do this unless you code specifically what you want to compare. Any object can refer to any other object. You could end up reading every object in the application, depending on where you started from.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a ready-made component to do this, but you can walk through the members of an object quite easily - here's some code which compares objects as part of a unit test - you'd need to replace the `Assert.AreEqual`s calls with some string formatting, or perhaps build-up a list of objects which describe differences, and then render them into HTML in a way which suits your site.

```
public static void CompareObjects(object expected, object actual)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in expected.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        var expectedValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(expected, null);
        var actualValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(actual, null);
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedValue, actualValue, "Comparing property " + propertyInfo.Name);
    }

    foreach (FieldInfo fieldInfo in expected.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(fieldInfo.GetValue(expected), fieldInfo.GetValue(actual), "Comparing field " + fieldInfo.Name);
    }
}
```